# How to access environment variable from CircleCI in fastlane

Tags: circleci, fastlane

I have an environment variable called `FIREBASE_TOKEN` stored on my CircleCI account. I want to access this in my fastfile, but I'm not sure how I can do that. My initial guess it to use `ENV['FIREBASE_TOKEN']`. Will this work?

e.g.

```
desc "Distribute app"
  lane :distribute do
    build_ios_app(...)
    firebase_app_distribution(
        app: "appid",
        testers: "tester1@company.com, tester2@company.com",
        release_notes: "notes",
        firebase_cli_token: ENV['FIREBASE_TOKEN']
    )
  end
```

Comment: Have you given your job access to the relevant environment variables either through a context or by setting them directly for that job? If so you should be able to use the above syntax.